# Get modified files from locally cloned Git repository using Java

Tags: java, git, jgit

In a cloned git repository, I want to pick only the files that are modified (i.e, files that are ready to commit or which are shown as **'modified'** if I run the command **'git status'**). I do not want to do it on date change comparison as files could have been modified on any day over a period of time.

I need the collection of file names with their absolute file paths.

Is there any such git utility in Java available? Or what will be the better approach?

Comment: "git add --all"  (or -A) ?

Comment: By pick you mean? If you want to apply particular commit to your local repo then it can be done.

Comment: @ZainUlAbideen I don't want to commit. The idea is to get the modified file names only. Preferably using Java I/O.

Comment: You can try something like [JGit](https://www.eclipse.org/jgit/) to operate git related stuff. For example, do `git status` and show the modified files.

Comment: @jackz314 Thanks. Something similar I was looking for. I will explore this library to see if it can help me.

Comment: @jackz314 JGit library was helpful in getting what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Set;

import org.eclipse.jgit.api.Git;
import org.eclipse.jgit.api.Status;
import org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.GitAPIException;

public class GitModifiedFileExtractor {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalStateException, GitAPIException {
        Git myGitRepo = Git.init().setDirectory(new File("C:\\myClonedGitRepo")).call();
        Status status = myGitRepo.status().call();
        Set<String> modifiedFiles = status.getModified();
        for (String modifiedFile : modifiedFiles) {
            System.out.println("Modified File - " + modifiedFile);
        }
    }
    // Similarly we can get files - added, missing, removed, untracked, etc., 
    // from status object.
}
```